# What did Solr match on?

Tags: solr, sunspot

Is it somehow possible to figure out what Solr match on?

Like this for example.

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :title
    text :actors do
      actors.map(&:name)
    end
  end
end
```

When searching for `Bruce` a list of `Bruce Willis` and `Bruce Almighty` should be possible to extract from Solr (Sunspot), if in fact `Bruce Willis` and `Bruce Almighty` where the strings Solr matched on.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

This information is available in Solr's `debug` block when providing the `debugQuery=on` parameter. Typically when I'm debugging with Sunspot, I'll check the logs for the URL that it is querying, and run that query against Solr directly with `debugQuery=on`.

The debugQuery output can be a bit involved. You can refer to the blog post [Debugging Search Application Relevancy Issues](http://www.lucidimagination.com/devzone/technical-articles/debugging-search-application-relevance-issues) for a bit of a breakdown on what you're seeing in there.

Comment: I cant get it to work as I want it to. I searched for `Bruce Willis`, just as in the example above. [Here](https://gist.github.com/36f604c2bbe380100692) is the result. I can't find anything in there that indicates that the original source is from the person (actor) `Bruce Willis`. This line for example `Person.find_by_name("Bruce Willis").id` returns `694`, there is no `694` id in the debug out put. I'm I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Have you tried reindexing? You may have stale data in your index.

Comment: I'm doing a reindex aws. 10 hours left :) I'll return with the result.

Comment: It's the same thing after reindexing my database.

Comment: Actually, if you dig into the debug output, you will see that the terms `bruce` and `willi` are being matched on `Movie` records, in their `actor_names_text` fields. This all seems to be as expected.

Comment: It occurs to me that perhaps you're trying to identify _which_ associated record was matched for the sake of your application, rather than simply debugging relevancy. In that particular case, you may need to break up your searches a bit. Either index and search People separately, or run distinct Movie searches that focus on either the title or the actor names.